# which one is the better approach to catch multiple exceptions at once?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

There are a number of ways to catch "Exceptions" in programming. It's always advisable to catch "known" exceptions inside programs without simply catch `Exception`.

To reduce unnecessary repetitive code fragments we can catch multiple exceptions at once and do further steps. I could find simple 2 methods to do that.

method 1:

```
catch (IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Exception found");
            throw ex;
        }
catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("Exception found");
            throw ex;
        }
```

method 2:

```
catch (IOException|FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("Exception found");
            throw ex;
        }
```

Which one is the better method to handle multiple exceptions at one in java? is there any better method to do that?

Comment: Method1 and Method2 do not do the same thing.  If there are no other exceptions then Method2 is better as it is self documenting code.

Comment: Sure this is Java?

Comment: Method 1 will only work in reversed order. A FileNotFoundException is an IOException, so if an IOExcpetion is catched first, you will never reach FileNotFoundException.

Comment: or is there any better method to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Please note, that you have to catch `FileNotFoundException` before catching `IOException` because a `FileNotFoundException` is an `IOException`. Otherwise you will never reach the `FileNotFoundException`. So in your case you could only catch `IOException` because it contains `FileNotFoundException`.

```
catch (IOException ex){ // does contain FileNotFoundException
    System.out.println("Exception found");
    throw ex;
}
```

Generally speaking: If you have the same code in your catch block, you should use a multi catch because otherwise you'd have duplicated code. I see no problem in that (in fact, that's why multi-catch has been introducted to Java).

But that's not always the case of course. If you have to treat exceptions differently you must define different catch blocks.

Answer (score -1):

There is another method. we can use if condition inside catch block for selection.

```
catch (Exception ex){
if(ex==IOException){
      System.out.println("Exception found");
      throw ex;}
else if (ex==FileNotFoundException){
      System.out.println("Exception found");
      throw ex;}
            }
}
```

Comment: Anld also we can use case selection too

Comment: This is neither valid Java code nor is it a good pattern. In this case, you would hide RuntimeExceptions for example. Please don't do this and use the default Java syntax instead. In fact this is a anti-pattern.